# Excel and PowerPoint to talk via SharePoint Libraries

Tags: 2013, excel, excel-services, powerpoint

We are looking into a way for an Excel file and PowerPoint file to exchange data.  I'm thinking Excel Web Services, OpenXML, SharePoint Office Apps and/or maybe CSOM.

Requirement is coming up to:

1. Allow Excel and PowerPoint file to “talk” to each other
2. Excel file changes will cascade to PowerPoint updates
3. PowerPoint updates are then extracted as an image and displayed on SharePoint home page
4. Email notification sent out

Initial System Architecture:

1. Create a basic SharePoint site using SP13 to include document libraries and lists.
2. Extract images generated from PowerPoint file stored on the site.
3. Generate a table in the PowerPoint file that is populated with data from an Excel file located elsewhere.

Use Case:

1. User makes change to number in cell within Excel file.
2. Upon saving changes, the revised number is updated in the table within the PowerPoint file.
3. A visual flag is generated in the changed cell within the table indicating a change has occurred.
4. Following the auto-update an new image is extracted from the PowerPoint file and displayed on the SP site.
5. After the SP site is automatically updated, an automated notification email is sent to anyone who requested this service

Is OpenXML, SharePoint Office Apps and CSOM the recommended way to go for Excel and PowerPoint file to “talk” to each other?

Would Excel Web Services be the choice for Excel and PowerPoint file to “talk” to each other?

Comment: Could you share the solution you went with?